# Category O for (Yangian) toroidal Lie algebras?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Suppose throughout that $g$ is a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and let us denote:
$$g_{[2]} := g \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}[v^{\pm 1}, t^{\pm 1}]$$
$$g_{[2]}^+ := g \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}[v^{\pm 1}, t]$$
and let us endow these with the following bilinear form:
$$(x v^m t^p, y v^n t^q)_{g_{[2]}} = -(x, y)_g \delta_{(m, p) + (n, q) = (0, \epsilon)}$$
wherein $(-, -)_g$ is some non-degenerate invariant bilinear form on $g$ (one might as well take the Killing form), $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta, and $\epsilon \in \{0, 1\}$; the sign choice matters if we want to put a Lie bialgebra structure on $\tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$ (I personally do, because I would like $\tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$ to be quantised by the affine Yangian $Y(\hat{g})$ somehow; see below) but otherwise, I believe that it can be ignored.

Next, denote by:
$$\tilde{g}_{[2]}, \tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$$
the universal central extensions of $g_{[2]}$ and of $g_{[2]}^+$ respectively.

My question is then: **has there been any attempt to define and study some kind of "category $O$" for the Lie algebras $\tilde{g}_{[2]}, \tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$, for either of the cases $\epsilon = 0, 1$ ?** Thanks in advance!

As for motivations, my personal reason for caring about this stems from the question of whether or not there exist bialgebra coproducts on affine Yangians; in particular, this means that I am more interested in the case $\epsilon = 1$. Let $\hat{g}$ denote the untwisted affine Kac-Moody algebra attached to g (cf. Chapter 7 of Kac's "Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras") and let $Y(\hat{g})$ denote the associated Yangian; for technical reasons, we need to assume also that $\hat{g}$ is simply laced (which in particular excludes the case $g \cong sl_2(\mathbb{C})$). In their paper "[Coproduct for the Yangian of an affine Kac-Moody algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05288)", Guay-Nakajima-Wendlandt noticed that, if $V_1, V_2$ are any two objects of the category $O$ of $Y(\hat{g})$ (cf. Definition 3.1 of loc. cit.) then there will be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism:
$$\Delta_{V_1, V_2}: Y(\hat{g}) \to End_{\mathbb{C}}(V_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_2)$$
given by particular formulas on the generators of $Y(\hat{g})$ in such a way that the algebra homomorphism looks like how a hypothetical bialgebra coproduct on $Y(\hat{g})$ "ought" to look like (cf. Theorem 4.9). At the same time, it is also known that $Y(\hat{g})$ is a flat graded deformation of $U(\tilde{g}_{[2]}^+)$, which leads me to wondering about whether - should there be some kind of category $O$ for $\tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$ - if one might obtain Lie algebra homomorphisms:
$$\delta_{V_1, V_2}: \tilde{g}_{[2]}^+ \to end_{\mathbb{C}}(V_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_2)$$
that somehow resembles the Lie bialgebra structure on $\tilde{g}_{[2]}^+$ that the Yangian $Y(\hat{g})$ supposedly quantises.